# Get tokens from lexemes

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Given a **token**, postgres can use a **dictionary** to find a set of **lexemes**.

```
select * from ts_lexize('english_stem', 'bananas');
 ts_lexize 
-----------
 {banana}
(1 row)
```

Is it possible to **reverse** this process, i.e. to convert a set of lexemes to a set of tokens?

If the entire set of possible tokens was known ahead of time, then `ts_debug` might work:

```
select lexemes, token from ts_debug('english', 'bananas banana kiwis') 
where lexemes is not null;

 lexemes  |  token  
----------+---------
 {banana} | bananas
 {banana} | banana
 {kiwi}   | kiwis
(3 rows)
```

Unfortunately, in my situation, I do not have the entire set of possible tokens.